# Chrome content-script makes a cookie; The cookie gets deleted when chrome restarts. How to make it stable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a problem when I want to write a cookie. I am using jQuery cookies plugin. I am going to write and read cookies in my chrome content-script.

Cookies work fine, I can read and write cookies and everything is right until the chrome restarts. When chrome restarts, my cookie gets deleted and when I want to read the cookie, returns null.

I use **$.cookies("NAME","VALUE");** to write and **$.cookies("NAME");** to read.

There is no problem until the chrome is running. Even by closing and opening tabs, there's no problem. But closing and opening chrome causes deleting my cookie. I'm pretty sure that my browser doesn't remove the cookie.

So, How do I make them stable, guys? Thanks in adventure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a session cookie. Did you set the expire time? With [this plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/) you can set it with:

```
$.cookie("NAME", "VALUE", { expires: 7 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting session cookies; that is the expected behavior.

If you want the cookies to persist, give them an expiration date.  For example:

```
$.cookie ('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```

will set the cookie to expire in a week.

See [the jQuery cookies plugin, usage guide](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#usage).

Comment: Thanks, you're right. i'm sorry cuz i can't accept two answers.

Comment: No problem; glad we could help.